# Tengo un problema con mi Docker Composer windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

soy usuario de Windows, el problema que tengo con el Docker es que me manda la siguiente leyenda al iniciar y las urls me las manda color rojo, la leyenda es:

***Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
parent. Are you in the right directory?
Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml***

antes no me hacia este problema simplemente después de unos meses inicie nuevamente las aplicación y me marca ese error.

Comment: Revisaste si el directorio en el que estás trabajando, en efecto tiene el archivo que te está pidiendo?

Comment: si y no tiene ese archivo, lo raro de todo es que intente en 3 computadoras diferentes y me sigue marcando ese error cuando hace unas semanas no lo marcaba, al final opte por instalar vagrant ya que hice todo lo posible por solucionarlo y no hubo éxito.